# Android OS kernel related queries

Tags: android, linux, memory, kernel, rtos

I was looking to write some case study on Android's kernel. This would be a part of my curriculum in the Advanced Operating systems class.
The primary focus that i wanted was the actual implementation of how priority queues are implemented in any RTOS just to relate it to the theory we have studied in the class.
But i came to know that finding information is really a big task rather than just having a great idea. :(
So for now i want to limit myself to either
1. Kernel (either process or memory) which will be very specific
or
2. Difference in Android and Linux OS
What i have observed is that though we have some information on both of them but the data given can be even seen in my text book. What i wanted was a practical difference.

I hope I would be getting some pointers in the direction.

Answer (score 2):

The Android Linux kernel and the mainline Linux kernel are close. There are several key differences:

1. Android has the major `wakelock` patches applied. These are not mainline. Google should reveal years of back and forth on this issue.
2. Android has the `binder` security model, mainline does not.
3. Android has an all new framebuffer to support SurfaceFlinger.
4. Hardware support for the phones. The mainline kernel does not have direct support for all of the ARM processors and devices. Consider the Android kernel trees an amalgam of Mainline+ARM(OMAP)+Vendor patches.
5. Specific embedded tuning.

However, 95+% of the code is the same in Mainline Linux vs Android Linux. Android is not an RTOS (the RT parts are handled in a separate processor on the radio modules) .

Comment: Good answer. One correction: The binder is about IPC, not security.One could argue that the Android security model also differs, but that is handled by the OS and not the kernel. There should also be one addition to this list: ashmem for sharing memory between processes. There are quite a few other differences as well, but they are rather small.

Comment: OK, i think i got what you wanted to say. if android is not a RTOS then i will do the my case study on how the implementation is being done for the process or memory. can you point me to some links or some code walkthroughs. what all i could find is either some definition(as in my textbook, which i have already learnt) or hard core code in the repository(difficult to understand). is there any easy way to relate what i have study and what is actually going there in the kernel? i know this may be bizzare but i need an intermediate point to start.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start learning is the Android git repositories: https://android.googlesource.com

Here are some politics, but eventually you find more links for yourself: http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/android-kernel-problems.html

Comment: The linked writeup has some severe mistakes in it.  Binder is not a security model, nor is the OpenBinder it links to what is used in Android (android has an extremely simplified version sharing nothing but the fundamental mechanism, in particular it has no discovery mechanism).  Neither kernel device drivers nor anything else in the kernel depend on Binder, it's a tool for user-mode OS and application services.  And it misses what actually is novel in the way of kernel security model, the hard-coding of certain user groups for kernel enforcement of privileges, for example networking.